# LUIS App created using "msbot clone services" not getting published to "PRODUCTION"

Tags: botframework

I have created LUIS App using following command `msbot clone services --folder Export --name <NAME_OF_BOT> --groupName <NAME_OF_GROUP> --luisAuthoringKey <LUIS_AUTHORING_KEY> --location westus --subscriptionId <AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID> --sdkLanguage Node --sdkVersion v4 --appId <APPLICATION_ID> --appSecret <APPLICATION_PASSWORD>`

Everything worked as expected except one thing. The LUIS App created is not available for consumption and always throws the error "model not published. please publish your model before hitting the endpoint."

Logged in to https://luis.ai > Selected the LUIS App > Clicked on Manage tab > Clicked on Keys and Endpoints on the left panel > Ensured URL reference slot has "Production" selected > Clicked on the Endpoint URL for "Starter_Key" Resource Name > appended a sample questions next to q= in the URL payload opened in browser

**Expected Result:** LUIS will be able to evaluate my utterance

**Actual Result:** model not published. please publish your model before hitting the endpoint.

For argument purpose tried to change the "URL referencing slot" from Production to Staging and retried. The expectation was met. Republish the already published app to Production and retried but the behavior was exactly same.

Just to ensure this is not a known problem even with Apps created directly on LUIS, went ahead and created a sample app using LUIS portal directly. Published only to Staging and tried to invoke the URL while "URL referencing slot" had Production selected. Got exact same error message. The published to Production and retried and everything worked as expected.

In summary this issue seem to be only with LUIS apps published using "msbot clone services ..." command. We are just not able to publish the app to production slot even though LUIS portal says it has been published.

Comment: Samir, this is a known problem that member of the Bot Framework Team filed an issue for. Track the investigation's progress on github here: https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/976

Comment: Thank you for the updates. Will retry after you rollout the hotfix and report.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was a bug in LUIS and has been fixed.